# AttributeError: 'Doctype' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, minify

I am using `django-htmlmin` to minify HTML. But getting `AttributeError: 'Doctype' object has no attribute 'name'` On my production server. But on my development environment everything works fine.
Here is the full Traceback:

```
{'levelname': ERROR,'time':24/Jan/2015 16:59:02,'module': base,'process': 1716,'thread' :156 'message':Internal Server Error: /'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\djangostack-1.7-0\apps\django\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\djangostack-1.7-0\python\lib\site-packages\htmlmin\middleware.py", line 44, in process_response
    parser=parser)
  File "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\djangostack-1.7-0\python\lib\site-packages\htmlmin\minify.py", line 39, in html_minify
    mini_soup = space_minify(soup, ignore_comments)
  File "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\djangostack-1.7-0\python\lib\site-packages\htmlmin\minify.py", line 61, in space_minify
    space_minify(child, ignore_comments)
  File "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\djangostack-1.7-0\python\lib\site-packages\htmlmin\minify.py", line 55, in space_minify
    if str(soup.name) in EXCLUDE_TAGS:
  File "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\djangostack-1.7-0\python\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 667, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'Doctype' object has no attribute 'name'
```

As soon as I set `HTML_MINIFY = False`. It fixed the issue. Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Issue](https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin/issues/81) is resolved by upgrading beautifulsoup to beautifulsoup4==4.3.2. Now everything is working fine.